# Google SEO - does it consider a domain with a www and one without as two separate sites?

Tags: seo

A friend of mine had a report done on an old site I built. One of the issues mentioned in the report was the following:

> Your website needs a www resolve.
>   Currently you can go to
>   http://urmarialarts.com or
>   http://www.urmartialarts.com which
>   means in Google's eyes you have two
>   websites with the same content. You
>   should set the hosting up so you are
>   redirected

Is this the case? And if so do I need to setup a 301 redirect on one of the domains to point to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and yes, for further information: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231

Comment: hm, seems that its possible to specify the preferred domain name with google. you could think also that as both domain names resolve to the IP address that search engines would conclude that the content is not a duplication. ah well!

Comment: @Sergio - It's technically possible to hava one site in www.site.com and another in site.com both using the same IP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based

Answer (score 1):

You should entirely avoid this problem by using a canonical link tag.  http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html